# Is there meta data I can read from SQL Server to know the last changed row/table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We have a database with **hundreds** of tables.

Is there some kind of **meta** data source in SQL Server that I can **programatically** query to get the name of the **last changed** table and row?

Or do we need to implement this **ourselves** with fields in each table called **LastChangedDateTime**, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of finding out when a table last had a modification, there is a sneaky way that can work to access this information, but it will not tell you which row was altered, just when.
SQL Server maintains index usage statistics, and records the last seek / scan / lookup and update on an index. It also splits this by user / system.

Filtering that to just the user tables, any insert / update / deletion will cause an update to occur on the index, and the DMV will update with this new information.

```
select o.name, 
max(u.last_user_seek) as LastSeek, 
max(u.last_user_scan) as LastScan, 
max(u.last_user_lookup) as LastLookup,
max(u.last_user_update) as LastUpdate 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats u
inner join sys.objects o on  o.object_id = u.object_id
where o.type = 'U' and o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
group by o.name
```

It is not ideal however, a heap has no index for a start - and I have never considered using it for production code as a tracking mechanism, only as a forensic tool to check obvious alterations.

If you want proper row level alteration tracking you will either have to build that in, or look at the SQL 2008 specific Change Data Capture feature.

Comment: +1 for idea of Change Data Capture: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3720361/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008----Change-Data-Capture--Part-I.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `[sys].[tables]` view will tell you when the table was created and last modified (in terms of schema, not insert, updates or deletes). To my knowledge there is no built-in information about last modified for each record in the database (it would take up a lot of space anyway, so it's probably nice not to have it). So you should add a last modified field yourself, and maybe have it updated automatically by a trigger.

Comment: sounds great, I'm looking around for how the exact sql statement would read, e.g. SELECT FILEGROUP_NAME (filestream_data_space_id) FROM sys.tables...

Comment: ok, this "select name,create_date,modify_date from sys.tables
WHERE create_date <> modify_date
ORDER BY modify_Date" gets the last STRUCTURAL change, but we need the last date that DATA was changed in any row

Comment: Now I see that you stated that, missed it at first, I think the Change Data Capture feature in SQL Server 2008 is looking like our best bet for this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the recovery model you might be able to get this from the transaction log using fn_dblog http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-6-Using-fn_dblog-to-tell-if-a-transaction-is-contained-in-a-backup.aspx

Comment: I wouldn't trawl the TLog for this information, as much as I have decoded a number of the entries by hand, it remains an undocumented format that is difficult to work with.

Comment: CDC trawls the log, but i guess its a more 'offical' way of doing it

Comment: Yes, in that they understand their own format :) Same as replication uses the log etc - it is not the use of the log that is an issue, but manually trawling it with ::fn_dblog().